# opsmanager application not able to connect to opsmanager database

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have installed opsmanager database in one instance and application in other instance
Taken points from [this](https://docs.opsmanager.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/install-simple-test-deployment/) link

1. In application database server when i `netstat -nltp` it shows 127.0.0.1:27017 running mongod
2. After installing application in other instance I edit the `mongo.mongoUri` as `mongodb://db_instance_publicip:27017` in `/opt/mongodb/mms/conf/conf-mms.properties`
3. When I start by sudo service mongodb-mms start is shows below error

   > uri=mongodb://db_instance_publicip:27017/?maxPoolSize=150} Error: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect.......

**Error: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=db_instance_publicip:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was facing the same issue. The issue in my case was that my Mongo DB was binding to only localhost thanks to this line in /etc/mongod.conf:

```
bindIp: 127.0.0.1  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
```

As the commented part in the same line suggests, I had to replace "127.0.0.1" with "0.0.0.0" and restart Mongo DB and it started working!